# Why is every algebraic function a holonomic function?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I was studying about holonomic functions and one friend told me that [algebraic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function) are all holonomic functions, but he is not aware of any proof.

I would be happy to know any proof of this, preferably constructive.

Comment: What do you mean by 'algebraic function'?

Comment: @Berci https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function